# static_cast<> and unrelated class concersion

Tags: c++

I have the following 2 classes:

```
 class B; 
 class A
 {
     public:
     A();
     operator B() const;
  };
  class B
  {
     public:
     B2();
  };
```

here, A defines implicit conversion operator to B class. Then C++ reference says the following " If an implicit conversion sequence from new_type to the type of expression exists, that does not include lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, function-to-pointer, null pointer, null member pointer, or boolean conversion, then static_cast can perform the inverse of that implicit conversion". It means that the following is to be compiled

```
  A a;
  B b=a;
  A a1=static_cast<A> (b);
```

but Xcode gives an error message

Comment: The latest standard(s) refer to "standard conversion" not "implicit conversion". I think that's important. This conversion is invalid.

Comment: Actually, I found your wording on cppreference. Maybe it's from an outdated version of the standard? See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Answer (score 5):

Your C++ reference is being imprecise. The *Standard* (C++14 §5.2.9/7) says,

> The inverse of any standard conversion sequence (Clause 4) not containing an lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), function-to-pointer (4.3), null pointer (4.10), null member pointer (4.11), or boolean (4.12)
>   conversion, can be performed explicitly using `static_cast`.

Notice that it says *standard* conversion sequence. `static_cast` cannot perform the inverse of a user-defined conversion. It is also not hard to see why this is; if `static_cast` were required to perform the inverse of user-defined conversion sequences, it would have to have the ability to reverse arbitrary algorithms. For example, if `A` holds a pair of integers and `B` holds a single integer, and `A::operator B()` multiplies together the two integers, then the inverse would have to factor the integer in `B`...